# Postback with setTimeout function using wrong?

Tags: javascript, settimeout, dopostback

I use the old system, developed on framework 1.0, and running now on framework 2.0
Source code is:

```
<select name="DropDownList1" AutoPostBack="true" id="DropDownList1" runat="server">
  <option selected="selected" value="One">One</option>
  <option value="Two">Two</option
</select>
```

Generated html:

```
<select name="DropDownList1" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'DropDownList1\',\'\')', 0)" id="DropDownList1">
  <option selected="selected" value="One">One</option>
  <option value="Two">Two</option>
</select>
```

Its not work until I remove quotes around __doPostBack. Why? 
I receive a javascript error 1032: Invalid character.
How I make it work?
Thanks!

Comment: This should work, in the sense that the quotes are not a problem: `setTimeout` allows a string argument that will be evaluated. What is the problem you encounter? *"Its not work"* is not very enlightening.

Comment: I tried your code, and get no such error. Can you provide a fiddle that reproduces the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Found here, after spent a hours to solve:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.scripting.vbscript/q_Yp5Ngczeo

Answer:
If you include a VBScript code block before any other code block on an
ASPX page, the following statement will fail in IE (and the error is
far from obvious since it is untrappable and says only that there is an
Invalid character on line 1, character 2):

"javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'anyASPXcontrol\',\'\')', 0)"

This is a bug in IE 6 and possibly earlier versions (I only have v6 to
play with.)  I do not know if it affects IE 7 as I have not installed
that for testing lately.  Note that even though the prefix of
"javascript:" is used, the setTimeout function assumes it's calling a
VBScript function, presumably because the first script block is a
VBScript block.

Comment: For the future I think it's important to note that this is exactly why you need to provide much better detail in your question. There's almost no chance anyone else could have worked this out because you didn't provide vital information you your question. You didn't mention IE6, you didn't mention using VBScript, and you only made a cryptic reference to "framework" 1.0 and 2.0. Now, we might be able to guess what framework you're talking about, but you'd make it a lot easier to help you if you were more specific.